# Woocommerce 3.0 get variation name

Tags: woocommerce, product-variations

Hi I had the following code that was working with old versions of Woocommerce to get an extract of the variation name and its price, which now doesn't work anymore after the WC upgarde to 3.0

```
function shortcode_handler($atts, $content = "", $shortcodename = "", $meta = "")
{
    $output = "";
    $meta['el_class'];

    global $woocommerce, $product;
    if(!is_object($woocommerce) || !is_object($woocommerce->query) || empty($product)) return;

    // $product = wc_get_product();

    $output .= "<div class='av-woo-calendar-button ".$meta['el_class']."'>";
    ob_start();?>

        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col" style="text-align:left; background-color:rgba(155, 199, 239, 0.5); vertical-align:middle;"><?php _e('Cruise', 'whale_dolphins'); ?></th>
                    <th scope="col" style="text-align:center;background-color:rgba(155, 199, 239, 0.5);"><?php _e('Places<br/>available', 'whale_dolphins'); ?></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php

            $args = array(
                'post_type'         => 'product_variation',
                'post_status'       => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page'    => -1,
                'orderby'           => 'title',
                'order'             => 'ASC',
               'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'key'       => '_stock',
                        'value'     => array('', false, null),
                        'compare'   => 'NOT IN'
                    )
                )
            );

            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

                            $product = new WC_Product_Variation( $loop->post->ID );
                    if (get_the_title( $loop->post->post_parent ) == 'CSR Expeditions Payment' || get_the_title( $loop->post->post_parent ) == 'Pagamento Spedizioni CSR')
                    {       
                        $variation_formatted_name = $product->get_formatted_name();
                        $variation_name_array = explode("&ndash;", $variation_formatted_name);
                        $variation_name = $variation_name_array[2];
                        $variation_price = $variation_name_array[3];
                        $variation_sku = $variation_name_array[0];
                        $variation_name_only = explode(":", $variation_name);
                        $variation_name_only = $variation_name_only[1];
                ?>

                <tr>
                    <td><?php  echo $variation_name_only ."&ndash;" . $variation_price; ?></td>
                    <?php
                        if (intval ($product->stock) >0)
                        { ?>
                            <td style="text-align:center; font-size: 13px; background-color:#70C940; color:rgba(255,255,255,1);"><?php echo intval ($product->stock); ?></td>
                        <?php
                        }
                        else
                        { ?>
                            <td style="text-align:center; font-size: 13px; background-color:#D11E1B;color:rgba(255,255,255,1);"> <?php echo intval ($product->stock); ?></td>
                        <?php    
                        }

                    ?>
                </tr>
                <?php
                    }
            endwhile; 

            ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    <?php

    $output .= ob_get_clean();
    $output .= "</div>";

    return $output;
}
```

In particular I imagine that the following part of code is to be modified

```
$product = new WC_Product_Variation( $loop->post->ID );
                    if (get_the_title( $loop->post->post_parent ) == 'CSR Expeditions Payment' || get_the_title( $loop->post->post_parent ) == 'Pagamento Spedizioni CSR')
                    {       
                        $variation_formatted_name = $product->get_formatted_name();
                        $variation_name_array = explode("&ndash;", $variation_formatted_name);
                        $variation_name = $variation_name_array[2];
                        $variation_price = $variation_name_array[3];
                        $variation_sku = $variation_name_array[0];
                        $variation_name_only = explode(":", $variation_name);
                        $variation_name_only = $variation_name_only[1];
```

Any suggestion on how can I fix it? Thank you very much

Comment: For example `$product->stock;` should be now [**`$product->get_stock_quantity();`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_get_stock_quantity) … And (Not completely sure) Instead of `$product = new WC_Product_Variation( $loop->post->ID );` you should try  `$product = wc_get_product($loop->post->ID);` … You have to test it with `print_r()` or `var_dump()` on the objects and arrays…

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec, I tried what you suggested but it didn't work. Concerning the stock, $product->stock wortks in the same way of $product->get_stock_quantity(). I can get the proper stock quantity. However the problem still remains in the variation name. I can get only the variation slug but not the full name, even if I use the function wc_get_product

Comment: By the way the code was based on the following example https://mikejolley.com/2011/12/05/woocommerce-output-a-simple-printable-stockinventory-report/

Answer (score 0):

**RESOLVED**

I found the solution which is posted here below for anyboduìy may need it.

With the new Woocommerce the command `$product->get_formatted_name();` returns a string as follows "product-name (#variation_id)"

With the variation_id however it is possible to get the attribute element slug from the postmeta table. With the slug you can get the attribute element name from the terms table.

```
$product = new WC_Product_Variation ($loop->post->ID);
          if (get_the_title( $loop->post->post_parent ) == 'CSR Expeditions Payment' || get_the_title( $loop->post->post_parent ) == 'Pagamento Spedizioni CSR')
          { 
            //1) I need to get the variation id == post id in wp_postmeta table
            // get the name and id of the variation in a string                 
            $variation_formatted_name = $product->get_formatted_name();
            //explode the string to get an array of the string
            $variation_formatted_name_array = explode("#", $variation_formatted_name);
            //get only the variation id (which comes along with a closed parenthesis
            $variation_id_ = $variation_formatted_name_array[1];
            //explode the string in an array made by the variation id and the parenthesis
            $variation_id = explode(")", $variation_id_);
            //get only variation id
            $variation_id_only = $variation_id[0];

            //2) 
            //get the taxonomy needed
            $taxonomy = 'pa_csr-dates';
            //get the meta value (= attribute slug) from the postmeta table through the variation_id (= post_id)
            $meta = get_post_meta($variation_id_only, 'attribute_'.$taxonomy, true);
            //get the variation name from the terms table through the slug (=$meta)
            $term = get_term_by('slug', $meta, $taxonomy);
            //get the variation name (attribute element custom name)
            $variation_name_only = $term->name; 
            $variation_price = $product->get_price();
          }
```